# How a Kardashev type 2 civilization with no FTL would conquer an analog of the Federation from *Star Trek*?

Tags: dyson-spheres, space-warfare

Let's say a Kardashev type 2 civilization composed of a dyson swarm discovers a galactic federation, likes what they see, and decides to take it. However the Kardashev type 2 civilization lacks FTL, and their enemy does not. how would the Kardashev type 2 civilization win against an such opponent?

Edit: for details about the K2, it's built around an orange dwarf, and has a fleet of over 31,000 ships powered by micro black holes, and armed with laser point defense and mass drivers, and with an average ship size of 20 KM.

the Federation on the other hand is only intended for exploration, and with no real warships of their own, and have half the number of ships as the K2.

Comment: This question needs way more details

Comment: Very hard to imagine a K2 culture not discovering something a less-than K2 did.  Also if they "like what they see", it *fundamentally* looks that way because it's a federation, so taking it over kinda doesn't work - joining it makes more sense as they'd presumably also get FTL tech.

Comment: This boils down to an essentially [Jominian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine-Henri_Jomini) question: "Which is more important, *mobility* or *mass*?" It's a trick question commonly asked of teenaged cadets -- both are important, though perhaps at different times. A winner must be able to use both.

Answer (score 4):

As I remember, Harry turtledove wrote a series of stories in which most civiilzations developed a form of faster than light travel when at about a 17th century technological level, and then their technological development slowed down and stopped, leaving them with interstellar travel while still at a pre industrial technological level.

But for some reason Earth avoided that discovery and became industrialized and developed advanced technology.  And so when aliens with pre industrial technology landed on Earth they were quickly defeated, Earth learned how to build faster than light spaceships, and went on to conquer a vast space empire.

So possibly in your story civilizations either invent faster than light travel or else develop to be K2 level civilizations, but not both.  Thus a K2 level civilization might possibly be much more advanced in everything except for space travel than the faster than light federation.

And how well a writer writes that part will determine how plausible that seems to the readers.

I think that a K2 culture that had many different Dyson swarms in many different star systems, and which included them all into a single political state (presumably a federal state of some type) would be more likely to want to invade and conquer a Star Trek like federation.

If they can successfully rule many star systems without faster than light space drive, they can rule with faster than light travel at least as many worlds as the target federation rules with faster than light travel.

So the plan would be to build many fleets of space battleships, each fleet capable of defeating the entire federation fleet if concentrated in one place to oppose their fleet. 
And then calculate how much larger and more powerful the federation might become in the possibly centuries or millennia it might take for the invasion fleets to reach their targets, and increase the size of the invasion fleets to compensate for that predicted increase.

The great military advantage of faster than light drive over slower than light drive is the ability to move much faster and thus concentrate superior military force at a given point to defeat the enemy forces there.

The only way to negate that advantage is to send a force to every point so powerful that it will probably defeat the entire enemy force if the enemy concentrates their entire military force at that point.

So the slower than light invaders will have to send an invasion force to each major star system in the faster than light federation that is capable of defeating the entire military force of the federation.  Thus the invasion fleets will conquer each and every single major star system in the faster than light federation no matter how the faster than light federation concentrates or disperses its forces.

Comment: I checked Amazon but Harry Turtledove has written a metric buttload of books.  Do you remember any titles?

Comment: excellent point! the federation would never be able to defeat the K2, and the K2 civilization would win this conflict. a K2 would regard building the Death Star from start to finish as both a minor expense, and a weekend project.

In addition to the ships you mentioned, they'd weaponize their dyson swarm, and launch volleys of billions of relativistic kinetic missiles called RKVs at all of the federation's planet's with each RKV impacting with a force equal to billions of thermonuclear weapons. The extinction of the dinosaurs would look like a household pest extermination job by comparison!

Comment: @Willk  I trie dlook up likely titles, and I think that the stories in question are "Harbig-Haro" 1984, under the name Eric G. Iverson, which should be set centuries after Earth expanded into interstellar space, and "The Road Not Taken" (1985) in which aliens land on Earth and are defeated by Humans.  http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48609  --    http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48826  It is a little disappointing to see that the series is so short.

Answer (score 3):

**Grecia capta, ferum vinctorem coepit**

= "Greece was captured, then captured its savage captor."

Which refers to the Roman conquest of Greece, followed by the wholesale adoption of Greek culture by the Romans.

Your primitives discover a Federation.  They like what they see.  They petition to become members and they are let in.  But your primitives are so energetic, charismatic and culturally adept that their influence quickly permeates every aspect of the Federation.  Persons of your primitive culture spread through the federation, and everywhere they go they are admired and copied.  Their opinions are earnestly solicited and even the most ordinary person can rise to a position of power.  Out in the Federation, never, ever does one of them buy his own drinks.  It does not hurt that by the standards of the Federation, your K2 people are amazingly good looking.

Within a few generations it is hard to tell who is an original primitive from your world and who is originally from the Old Federation, but is copying the lifestyle and speech of your primitives.  Your primitive civilization has prevailed, by dint of awesomeness.  They never needed to fire a shot.

Answer (score 2):

If the Federation uses its technological advantage correctly, the K2 civilisation probably can't conquer them. Being limited to STL spaceflight means that they take years to travel between stars. This gives the Federation time to build warships and deploy them.

There are also some very effective military tactics that an FTL combatant can use against an STL opponent. The STL side is forced to accelerate to quite high velocities, say a few percent of the speed of light, to make interstellar transits in any useful time. That makes FTL cargo vessels positioning rocks along their trajectory highly effective. They have laser point defence, but grains of sand leaking through that are very damaging. At 1% of the speed of light, a 1-gram impactor hits with the energy of about 18 tons of TNT.

It makes far more sense for the K2 civilisation to make friends with the Federation, learn the secret of FTL travel, re-equip their ships, and then start the war.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the "no FTL" problem first.

Without FTL, your enemy has millennia to react to what you're doing, so any battle plan you've made will be hilariously far out of date by the time you get to the enemy. If you have a massive mobility disadvantage and your motives aren't obvious at first, there's no reason why you wouldn't try to fix the disadvantage nonviolently before starting an otherwise impossible war.

**Step one:** get a friendly-looking contact vessel to meet up with their nearest system, barter or negotiate for the specifications to putting together an FTL drive (you've got loads of resources and such, after all), and transmit it back home.

**Step two:** employ your absolutely obscene production advantage (a K2 has to be able to disassemble planets and wipe out asteroid fields — probably with von Neumann probes — to get enough material for its Dyson sphere, whereas your average Federation-type is generally not shown to have this capability) to manufacture trillions or quadrillions of massive automated starships out of every planet you can get your hands on.

(This wouldn't have been an option if you hadn't gotten FTL first; with the amount of time you'd be giving your enemies to prepare, they'd have militarized by accelerating their own industry to the point where they, having more planets than you, can get a vastly larger and more modern fleet together.)

**Step three:** deploy into battle across the galaxy as fast as possible before they realize you're going ahead with step two.

Comment: it can be even millions of years before a fleet from an non FTL civilization to arrive. SO in all likelihood, the K2 would go on the defensive before it finds out more about its new enemy. Plus I am deciding the K2 is a machine civilization made up of living machines.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not limit the FTL engines?**

For example:

Only large ship carriers can use FTL and after each jump, they need several Terran days to "recharge".

The FTL civilisation is mainly composed of explorers. So, here's a big chance this civilisation is also more peace, commerce, and/or science-based. These huge exploration carriers would transport scientists, diplomates, merchants, and some light scouts.

Once a carrier arrives in a system, their drive is depleted and it takes several days before it can jump again. This is great for an explorers civilisation. During that time, they can use smaller ships to explore the new system. As do scientific research and look for other intelligent beings. Beings that would like to join the federation or open a commercial depot.

Of course, in times of war, these large ships are sitting ducks. Your K2 civilisation only will have to take a couple of them. Then swap its exploration ships with light fighters. And finally, check their onboard database where the next one is.

If the FTL federation is not belical, there's a big chance they're not prepared for total war. Their ships are all over the galaxy/local cluster/whatever depending on the scale of your world.

**The FTL ships travel faster than they can communicate**

Here it's simple. If we retake my previous example. We can state that their communication network is slower than their huge STL ships. It's then easy to imagine a scenario where the destress signals arrive after the taken carriers.

**The FTL federation thinks they're alone**

What if the FTL federation is made of all federations of the same species? A species that expanded all over their local cluster never meeting any other life? This for thousands of years? A civilisation that does not know war. And one day, they confronted with your greedy K2 space barbarians. Another kind of civilisation. That are depleting all the resources of their star system and in need of new places to sack.

One will go saying: "I come in peace" while the other will prepare their BBQ to feast on them.